# Merge ranges using matrix formulas

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a custom function that uses a range of coordinates, and a range of values to be uploaded into a database. E.g.:

Coordinates, let's say A1:D4

```
Coordinate2.1|Coordinate2.2|Coordinate2.3|Coordinate2.4
Coordinate3.1|Coordinate3.2|Coordinate3.3|Coordinate3.4
Coordinate4.1|Coordinate4.2|Coordinate4.3|Coordinate4.4
```

```
Values, let's say A6:A9
100
110
130
150
```

then the function: 
=UPLOAD(A1:D4,A6:A9)

unfortunately this is not very convenient because it has to be completely "normalized" (1 row per value). Let's say that the content of B1:B4 is now in H1:H4 (meaning, the range is no longer contiguous)

What I am looking for is a way to "merge" the ranges, so that I can build the A1:D4 range from matrix formula, e.g.:

A1:D4 => MERGE(A1:A4,H1:H4,C1:D4)

is this possible ?

Comment: Don't understand what you are talking about.  Where are the data in A1:D4 come from? What is H1:H4? What does it have to do with A6:A9 and your upload function?

Comment: in A1:D4 these are just values that are entered manually. regarding H1:H4 I understand it was confusing, I edited the question. A6:A9 are the values that must be uploaded

Comment: `Union()` could be the function you could look for. But remember when dealing with non-contiguous ranges, you needs to use the `Range.Areas` properties instead of just the Range object.

Comment: so it means that it would not be possible without VBA right ?

Comment: Correct.  I don't aware of any Excel formula that could do the work.